# Openxlsx protect sheet but allow entering of values

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am using excel templates to collect data from various people. To minmize the chances of people changing the structure of the templates I wanted to protect the sheets, but still allow them to fill in the data values that I want.

I was happy that i found a forked version of the openxlsx package that has included a function `protectWorksheet` to do this, [Link](https://rdrr.io/github/awalker89/openxlsx/). But when I use the function, I cannot adjust the function so that one can still fill values.

I dont really have an MWE besides the function from the example from the [help file](https://rdrr.io/github/awalker89/openxlsx/man/protectWorksheet.html#heading-3). How do I adjust the example to still allow filling in values? Is it possible?

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "S1")
writeDataTable(wb, 1, x = iris[1:30,])
# Formatting cells / columns is allowed , but inserting / deleting columns is protected:
protectWorksheet(wb, "S1", protect = TRUE, lockFormattingCells = FALSE, lockFormattingColumns = FALSE, lockInsertingColumns = TRUE, lockDeletingColumns = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "pageSetupExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Reinhold Kainhofer, you could control this using `createStyle`.

Download the `openxlsx` package from the github: https://github.com/kainhofer/openxlsx.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "S1")
writeDataTable(wb, 1, x = iris[1:30,])
# Formatting cells / columns is allowed , but inserting / deleting columns is protected:
protectWorksheet(wb, "S1", protect = TRUE, lockFormattingCells = FALSE, lockFormattingColumns = FALSE, lockInsertingColumns = TRUE, lockDeletingColumns = TRUE)

#This line allows specified cells to be unlocked so that users can enter values.
addStyle(wb, "S1", style = createStyle(locked = FALSE), rows = 1:10, cols = 1)

saveWorkbook(wb, "pageSetupExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: terrific. I have to try this at home, because it won´t work on my Office Computer. But indeed thanks to Reinhold Kainhofer